# Load static JSON data from URL for ExtJS grid panel

Tags: json, extjs, gridpanel, http-proxy, jsonstore

I tried to implement a grid panel using data from a JSON file which is located on the same domain as the Javascript file containing the ExtJs code. I'm using ExtJs 3.4.

The grid shows up but without any data in it. Firebug shows an error message that tells me that there is an error in the first line of the JSON file ("not well formed"). I have validated the JSON file and everything is ok.

Here is my code:

```js
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url: 'data.json',
        root: 'rows',
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: [{
            name: 'person',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'product',
            type: 'string'
        }]
    });

    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        id: 'gridPanel',
        title: 'Grid example',
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
        renderTo: 'grid-example',
        store: myStore,
        columns: [{
            header: 'Person',
            dataIndex: 'person'
        }, {
            header: 'Product',
            dataIndex: 'product'
        }]
    });
});
```

My JSON data is:

```js
{
    "rows": [{
        "person": "Jamie Avins",
        "product": "Ladder"
    }, {
        "person": "Ed Spencer",
        "product": "Spanner"
    }]
}
```

Do you have any ideas what's wrong? Can somebody give me some hints?

Thanks in advance!

Seha

Comment: is it call to data.json has been fired ? check in console

Comment: hi bensiu, thanks for your hint.I set autoLoad to true and also tried myStore.load().The data was loaded but firebug shows that it is not well formed.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'rows'
}
```

in your `JsonStore` and validate your json response.

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and the exact JSON string cut and pasted from your example. It worked just fine using Grails to return the string (not reading from a file). Firebug did not complain. Looks like the file itself could be the issue, maybe a hidden character is creeping in.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your answer. What do you mean exactly with "using Grails to return the string" ? I validated the JSON file and no hidden characters are in it. Firebug stops at the very first line complaining "not well formed" marking the first opening brace {.

Comment: Animal, what I meant by using Grails is that I had the Grails application server return the string rather than reading the string from a file. It is possible that even though the opening brace is marked that there is a problem elsewhere in the file. Maybe Firebug doesn't like a trailing line return or perhaps the quotation marks are the special curly Word kinds instead of the standard straight ones. Also, is Firebug getting the entire string or is it truncated or have something appended?

Comment: Hi John!Unfortunately, I was unable to write back sooner.I solved the problem. I installed the server again and changed some confings refering to the post http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?7424-Help!-I-can-t-even-load-docs&s=7737c6eb0807084adc6a2f5ff12bcda8 After that everything was fine.